# Identifying a certain element of $E^{2,0}_2$ with the orientation class of an oriented spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I'm interested in filling the details of the well known computation, via AHSS of $E^*(\mathbb{C}P^n)$; where $(E,x_E)$ is an oriented spectrum.

It is supposed to be easy, yet every proof I've read skip a (obvious?) detail which now I want to address. Let $i_n\colon \mathbb{C}P^n\to \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ be the usual inclusion.

> Let us denote with $\mathbb{Z}[i_n^*x_H]/(i_n^*x_H)^{n+1}$ the cohomology ring $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^n)$. AHSS is multiplicative so everything boils down to prove that the element $$i_n^*x_H\otimes \imath \in E^{2,0}_2 \cong E^2((\mathbb{C}P^n)_2,(\mathbb{C}P^n)_1)\cong \widetilde{E}^2(\mathbb{C}P^1)$$ coincides with $i_n^*x_E$.

Once we know this the result is clear since the AHSS collapses and the stable page is a free $\pi_*E$-module.

In the additional hypothesis that $E$ is connective, then I can indeed manage to show that $i_n^*x_E=i_n^*x_H\otimes \imath$ (there is a little identification going on here): using l.e.s. of the pair $(\mathbb{C}P^n,\mathbb{C}P^{n-1})$ one gets $\widetilde{E}^2(\mathbb{C}P^n)\cong \widetilde{E}^2((\mathbb{C}P^n)_2)$ and using the iso $E^2(\mathbb{C}P^n)\cong \widetilde{E}^2(\mathbb{C}P^n)\oplus E^2(*)$ one has the claim.

But I want to drop this hypothesis. On every reference I found (Adams' Stable homotopy and generalised homology Lemma 2.5 page 39, Kochman's Bordism, Stable Homotopy and Adams Spectral Sequences prop 4.3.2 and in [Ravenel](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/ravenel2.pdf) Lemma 4.1.4) it is always given as obvious, without any assumption on $E$ other than being a ring spectrum and being oriented. I'm wondering now if I'm missing something really trivial

**EDIt:** This is an argument I sketched down and I'd love to have some feedback about it:

Let me fix some notation: $ i_n \colon \mathbb{C}P^n \to \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ is the usual inclusion, and $ y_E$ is the image of the orientation class in the unreduced second cohomology group of $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$.

The first step is to identify a certain element in the AHSS for $ \mathbb{C}P^1$ with the orientation $ i_1^* y_E$. Recall that $ H^*(\mathbb{C}P^n)\cong \mathbb{Z}[y]/(y^{n+1})$

> **Claim 1**: The element $ y \otimes \imath \in E^{2,0}$ represents the orientation class $ i_1^*(y_E)$.

**Proof of Claim 1**: Consider the AHSS for $\mathbb{C}P^1$:
[image]
Since the edge homomorphism for the AHSS is always surjective, we have that the only possible non-zero differentials (the differentials of the 2nd page starting from the zero-th column to the second one) are trivial. This implies that the spectral sequence collapses. Since the second page is generated multiplicatively by $ y\otimes \imath \in E^{2,0}_2$ and it is a free graded $ \pi_*E$-module (i.e. the extension problem is trivial) the isomorphism $ E^2(\mathbb{C} P^1)\xrightarrow{\cong} E^{0,2}_2 \oplus E^{2,0}_2$ maps $ i_1^*(y_E) \mapsto y \otimes \imath$ ( $ E_2^{0,2} =E^2(\ast) $ and the other is the reduced cohomology group).

> **Claim 2**: The AHSS for $ \mathbb{C} P^n$ collapses at the second page and we have that $ y \otimes \imath \in E_2^{2,0}$ represents the orientation class $ i_n^*(y_E)$

**Proof of Claim 2**:  Let us have a look at the AHSS for $ \mathbb{C} P^n$:
[image]

Since the AHSS is multiplicative and thanks to the ring structure of the second page, it's enough to show that the element $ y \otimes \imath \in E_2^{2,0}$ is an infinite cycle. In fact, one proceed inductively using the fact that any other element in the previous page (i.e. in the second page) is a $ \pi_*E$-linear combination of powers of $ y\otimes \imath$. Consider the inclusion $ i_1^n \colon \mathbb{C} P^1 \to \mathbb{C} P^n$. We know that $ i_n^*(y_E)$ is sent to $ i_1^*(y_E)$ by the fact that $ (i_1^n)^*i_n^*=i_1^*$. Now recall that $ i_1^n$ induces a map of spectral sequences. Since we know that AHSS for $ \mathbb{C} P^n$ converges a priori to $ E^*(\mathbb{C}P^n)$ ($ \pi_*E$ is required to be bounded below by Kochman and Adams in another chapter) there is an element in the stable page $ E_{\infty}^{p,q}$, for some $ p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ which is a representative of $ i_n^*(y_E)$.

By Claim 1, we already know that the representative of $ i_1^*(y_E)$ lies in $$ E_{\infty}^{2,0}\cong F^2 E^2(\mathbb{C} P^1)/F^3 E^2(\mathbb{C} P^1)$$ Now suppose that the class of $$ i_n^*(y_E)\in F^p E^{p+q}(\mathbb{C} P^n)/F^{p+1} E^{p+q}(\mathbb{C} P^n)$$ since the inclusion preserves the filtration, it would send our class to an element lying in $ F^p E^{p+q}(\mathbb{C} P^1)/F^{p+1} E^{p+q}(\mathbb{C} P^1)$, but since we already established that the image of $$ i_n^*(y_E)\in F^2 E^2(\mathbb{C}P^1) / F^{3} E^2(\mathbb{C}P^1)$$ it must be that $ p\geq 2$ and $ q=0$ (Since $ F^pE^2(\mathbb{C} P^n)\subseteq F^{p-1}E^2(\mathbb{C} P^n)$). By definition of the filtration for the cohomological AHSS, if this element lies in $ F^p E^2(\mathbb{C}P^n) / F^{p+1} E^2(\mathbb{C}P^n)$ for $ p>2$ in particular its representatives lie in $$ F^2 E^2(\mathbb{C}P^n)$$ meaning that when restricted to $\mathbb{C}P^1$ they are all zero (it is crucial here that the inclusion identifies the 2 skeleton of $ \mathbb{C}P^n$ with $ \mathbb{C}P^1$). Since we know that the restriction to $ \mathbb{C}P^1$ of the orientation $ i_n^*(y_E)$ is a non-zero element, it must be $ p=2$ and $ q=0$. This shows that we have to look for a representative for $ i_n^*(y_E)$ in $E_{\infty}^{2,0}$. Consider the following diagram, where $ E_r'^{p,q}$ will denote the group in position p,q, page r of the AHSS for $ \mathbb{C}P^n$:

[image]

The lower map is an isomorphism since it is the map induced between the second singular cohomology groups of $ \mathbb{C} P^1$ and $ \mathbb{C} P^n$. The diagram implies that the unique preimage of the representative of $ i_1^*(y_E)\in E^2(\mathbb{C}P^1)$, which by Claim 1 is identified $ y \otimes \imath$, can only be the element $ y \otimes \imath$ in $ E_2'^{2,0}$.

Comment: I am not sure that cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients is actually necessary to understand the proof. It is just directly known that $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^n; E^*) \cong E*[x]/x^{n+1}$ and here we can take as $x$ the pullback of an arbitrary $E^*$-module generator in $\tilde{H}^2(\mathbb{CP}^1, \mathbb{CP}^1;E^*) \cong \tilde{E}^*(\mathbb{CP}^1)$.

Comment: @LennartMeier well yes, is it UCT right? I implicitly used it to write down my generator as $x_H\otimes \imath$ where $\imath$ is a $E^*$-module generator. So cohomology with integer coefficients is used to basically prove what you claim (I'm sure there are other ways, but I'm following what the refereces I wrote above suggest)

Comment: @Riccardo Can you clarify your definition of an oriented spectrum for me? The definition that I am used to is typically that you have a chosen element $x_E \in \tilde E^2(\Bbb{CP}^\infty)$ whose restriction to $\tilde E^2(\Bbb{CP}^1)$ is a particular fixed generator.

Comment: @TylerLawson yes, together with $E$ is ring spectrum. (obvious but just to be clear once and for all).
Kochman even asks for $\pi_*E$ being bounded below.

Comment: You might like to look at treatments of the equivariant case, where it is necessary to be a bit more careful and explicit about some details.  One version is in Sections 4 and 5 of a memoir of mine at http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211058.pdf

Comment: Dear Prof. @Strickland , thanks for your link, but due to my lack of experience I'm having an hard time in "extracting" the information I need from it. Could you please point me in the right direction where to look in these two sections?